# Ionic alert to cant added check box and text filed in same alert

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm try to add input text filed and check box in my alert but I cant do it correctly please help me to fix it,,

I want display text box and check box fields in my alert

This is my code

```
doPrompts() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add new add-on',
      message: "",

      inputs: [
        {

          placeholder: 'Select category',

        },
        {
          placeholder: 'Description',


        },
        {
          placeholder: 'Units',


        },
        {
          placeholder: '$ 00.00',


        }
      ],

      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Add',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Saved clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  }
```

Comment: which version of ionic?

Comment: sir Im used  ionic 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.Check the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/).

> Alerts can also include several different inputs whose data can be passed back to the app. Inputs can be used as a simple way to prompt users for information. Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all accepted, **but they cannot be mixed**.

If you need a form with different types of input. You will need to create an separate **component** having a form with both textbox input and select input and show as a [modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SelectForm);
modal.present();
```

Comment: Sir,please tel me Model is good option to change for my alert?

Comment: depends on your design... You are using alert assuming you dont want a full page. The next closest thing is a modal

Comment: sir, Ok thanks for the guide

Comment: no problem...:)